# Does AZcopy have a command line option to bulk upload multiple files in one invocation?

Tags: azure, azcopy

Currently we can set all files from a local folder or files patterns using the "pattern" attribute, but we need to upload multiple files from a local folder to blob storage in single command invocation. Is it possible to do this?

For example source folder contain more files, I need to send selected files in a single invocation, not use loop. Any way to specify selected files name in command line by coma separated value.

Syntax:

```
AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder /Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer /DestKey:key /S
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, can you please rephrase? I tried running the command above and it works in my opinion as expect. Running azcopy /Source:c:\temp\ /Dest:https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/ /DestKey:<Key> /S will copy recursively all files from C:\Temp\ to the specified container.

Comment: Yes, we can upload all files inside a source folder, But I need to upload selected files in commandline.

Answer (score 1):

For now, Azcopy only supports a single folder or file as the value of `/Source`.
And only one value for the parameter `/Pattern`.

So if you have to use one single AzCopy command to upload specific files, I recommend you modify file name with the same prefix, like upload-filename.extension. And you can use the `/Pattern:upload-*` to achieve your goal.

If there are to many files or the file name can't be changed according to your requirement, a code snippet may be a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Using `--include-path` should solve your problem.

```
azcopy copy '<local-directory-path>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<file-share-or-directory-name><SAS-token>' --include-path <semicolon-separated-file-list>
```

This was taken from the official azcopy documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files#upload-specific-files